Sources to study the holomorphic continuation of $\zeta(2s)E(\tau,s)$, where $E(\tau,s)$ is the real-analytic Eisenstein series
I am studying the paper EISENSTEIN SERIES AND THE RIEMANN
ZETA-FUNCTION, by D. Zagier. He says that the function $\zeta(2s)E(\tau,s)$ has a holomorphic continuation to all $s$ except for a simple pole at $s = 1.$ I found the proof that the function of $s$ is holomorphic for $Re(s)>1$ at some lecture notes by A. J. Scholl.
However, I want to see the analytic continuation. Many papers say "it is well known that $\zeta(2s)E(\tau,s)$ has analytic continuation to the entire $\mathbb{C}$ except in $s=1,$ where there is a pole", but none of them prove it. An exemple is the paper "Asymptotic expansions ofthe
non-holomorphic Eisenstein series", by Takumi Noda, where there is the Fourier expansion of that function and a functional equation, but there is no proof of these facts or about the analytic continuation.
Do you have tips of sources where there is the proof of the holomorphic continuation of $\zeta(2s)E(\tau,s)$? Or I can't find it because it is easy to see? If this is the case, do you have tips to help me to see why the analytic continuation holds?
Zagier says that the function $E(\tau,s)$ has a meromorphic continuation to all $s$, but his proof is really short, killing almost the entire proof. I also would like to see this proof with more details.

You can also continue $E(\tau,s)$ by following an argument similar to that of $\zeta(s)$. Define
$$
G(w)=\sum_{m,n\in\mathbb Z}e^{-{\pi w\over y}|m\tau+n|^2}.
$$
Then it follows from Poisson summation that
$$
G(\tau,w)=w^{-1}G(\tau,w^{-1}).\tag{$*$}
$$
Moreover, there is
$$
2\pi^{-s}\zeta(2s)\Gamma(s)E(\tau,s)=\sum_{(m,n)\ne(0,0)}{(y/\pi)^s\over|m\tau+n|^{2s}}=\int_0^{+\infty}w^{s-1}[G(\tau,w)-1]\mathrm dw,
$$
so breaking the integral into $\int_0^1$ and $\int_1^{+\infty}$ and applying ($*$) as one does in $\zeta(s)$ give
$$
2\pi^{-s}\zeta(2s)\Gamma(s)E(\tau,s)=\int_0^1(w^s+w^{1-s})[G(\tau,w)-1]{\mathrm dw\over w}+{1\over s(s-1)},
$$
which continues $\zeta(2s)E(\tau,s)$ to a meromorphic function with a pole at $s=1$.

Zagier says "the only singularity for $Re(s)>1/2$ is a simple pole at $s=1$". This phrase made me think that there is some singularity for $Re(s)\leq 1/2,$ but you said that there is none. Is this right?

I just edited: $\zeta(2s)E(\tau,s)$ only has a singularity at $s=1$, so your statement is correct.

I understood now. Thank you so much!

Sorry, how did you get that equality between the sum and the integral? Do you have any source? Zagier does it but I do not know how.  Please @TravorLZH

It follows from the following identity of $\Gamma(s)$: For $\lambda>0$, there is $$\int_0^{+\infty}w^{s-1}e^{-\lambda w}\mathrm dw={\Gamma(s)\over\lambda^s}.$$

Do you have any source about the last equality? I didn't get it and I don't see why the analytic continuation holds from it. I tried to do like in link but couldn't do it.

That's just a Laplace transform identity

See Chapter 3, section 1 on Eisenstein Series in Goldfeld's book Automorphic Forms on $\mathrm{GL}(n, \mathbb{R})$. This appears as Theorem 3.1.10 there. The section is approximately $5$ pages long and very approachable.
Broadly, you first explicitly compute that the Eisenstein series has Fourier expansion
$$ E(z, s) = y^s + \rho_0(s) y^{1-s} + c(y, s) \sum_{n \neq 0} \rho_n(y, s) e^{2 \pi i n x}$$
where
$$ \begin{align}
c(y, s) &= \frac{2 \pi^2 \sqrt{y}}{\Gamma(s) \zeta(2s)}, \\
\rho_0(s) &= \sqrt{pi} \frac{\Gamma(s - 1/2) \zeta(2s - 1)}{\Gamma(s) \zeta(2s)} \\
\rho_n(y, s) &= \sigma_{1 - 2s}(n) \lvert n \rvert^{s - 1/2} K_{s - 1/2}(2 \pi \lvert n \rvert y).
\end{align}$$
Here $\sigma$ is the divisor function and $K$ is the modified $K$-Bessel function.
Once you have the explicit Fourier coefficients, you can directly check the functional equation and growth in $s$ to get meromorphic continuation.
You could also look at Iwaniec's Topics in the Classical Automorphic Forms for a different presentation and in slightly greater generality.
